# why Gzip Compression htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, server, compression, gzip

I copied below mentioned Gzip code in htaccess file which was saved in hostgator root folder.
But after I check from Gzip testing tools it makes no different. I tried many codings and they also did not work.

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Maybe the module that the `ifmodule` directive is explicitly checking for here, isn't actually available on the server ...?

Comment: You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper. Do you get an error?